# Trying to use Logstash to index FROM Cloudwatch Logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

So we have logs (apache, tomcat, etc) stored in Amazon CloudWatch Logs.
I'm trying to use Logstash to index from AWS and send them over to Elasticsearch/Kibana.

I can't seem to find a plugin to accomplish this.
Has anyone tried this and was successful?
I don't want the metrics, just the logs stored in AWS Logs.

Comment: how about this https://github.com/awslabs/cloudwatch-logs-subscription-consumer and https://github.com/awslabs/cloudwatch-logs-subscription-consumer/blob/master/configuration/cloudformation/cwl-elasticsearch.template

Comment: Thank you! I'll check it out.

Comment: so I'm trying to use this template as is, just to see how it works with kinesis. I get "template validation error: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [AWS: : AccountId, AWS: : Region] in the Resources block of the template". Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Other posters have mentioned that CloudFormation templates are available that will stream your logs to Amazon Elasticsearch, but if you want to go through Logstash first, this logstash plugin may be of use to you:

https://github.com/lukewaite/logstash-input-cloudwatch-logs/

This plugin allows you to ingest specific CloudWatch Log Groups, or a series of groups that match a prefix into your Logstash pipeline, and work with the data as you will. It is published on RubyGems, and can be installed like a normal Logstash plugin: `bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-input-cloudwatch_logs`.

Comment: its best if you copy the esencial into your response but keep the link.

Answer (score 3):

As already [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32320425/trying-to-use-logstash-to-index-from-cloudwatch-logs#comment52516809_32320425) by BMW, AWS has just introduced a dedicated [CloudWatch Logs Subscription Consumer](https://github.com/awslabs/cloudwatch-logs-subscription-consumer), which provides one click access to a complete CloudWatch Logs + Elasticsearch + Kibana stack by means of a resp. [AWS CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) template, as further illustrated in the [introductory blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cloudwatch-logs-subscription-consumer-elasticsearch-kibana-dashboards/).

Given you seem to have an ELK stack readily available, it shouldn't be too complex to adjust the AWS [sample template](https://github.com/awslabs/cloudwatch-logs-subscription-consumer/blob/master/configuration/cloudformation/cwl-elasticsearch.template) to target your own endpoints instead.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to comb through it and see how I can eliminate the ES/kibana part and attach it to my endpoints.

Comment: The tutorial linked is a bit more difficult than I thought. Does this need kinesis?

Comment: And I copied the new dashboards and now I can't reach my ES server in Kibana. Says connection failed but ES is running.

Comment: How can I modify this so that I can use my existing ES cluster? I can't seem to find a method.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the CloudFormation template (as per BMW's answer) it needs to be customized, part of this would be providing your account ID and region as a [CF Resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resources-section-structure.html).
AWS: : AccountId and AWS: : Region are pseudo parameters that return the AWS account ID of the account in which the stack is being created, such as 123456789012, and a string representing the AWS Region in which the encompassing resource is being created, such as us-west-2. (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html)